# Passing Json object based on user selection in a tableview swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, tableview

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJAMU.jpg)Hi all I'm working on a project where when the user selects a particular cell in a table view, it should show them the data( which is a JSON Decoded object), Now I did all the networking stuff but not sure how to pass the values in such a way that when the user selects a particular cell, corresponding values should appear.

This is the contents of my tableview

```
var items = [Canada,Delhi,Mumbai,London]
```

When the user selects pen then the first value(kindly see my screenshot) should be displayed, Also I don't want to store these values as a hardcoded value, I want it to update whenever the user taps on that cell, I've added my networking struct, I'm new here so forgive me if there is any error in my question.
Thank You!

struct StateManager {

```
func geturl(){
    let url = "https://api.covidindiatracker.com/state_data.json"
networking(stateUrl: url)
}



func networking(stateUrl : String){
    
    if  let url = URL(string: stateUrl){
        
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print("Error fetching Data")
                return
            }else{
                //This is the decoded Data
                if  let safeData = data{
                    do{
                    let json = try JSON(data: safeData)
                        for i in 0..<38{
                            if let total = json[i]["confirmed"].int{
                                print(total)
                        }
                        }

                    }catch{
                        print("Error ")
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: What data type are the things in `items`?  The normal way of doing what you're asking is to have an array of what you want to pass and choose the correct one by using the row of the selected index path to pick it from the array.

Comment: @PhillipMills Hi, items is an array of strings and value it should have is of type Int

Comment: I suggest creating a custom struct or class that has a `name` property and a `content` property.  The name should match your array of strings for display in the table view and the matching content is your decoded object to pass as detail.